# Get a collection based on generic type

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I have a class that contains a number of generic collections of different types.

```
public class InMemoryDatabase
{
    public HashSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Truck> Trucks { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Bike> Bikes { get; set; }
}
```

How can I retrieve a collection based on the generic type?

E.g.

```
public HashSet<TEntity> GetCollection<TEntity>()
{
   //how to retrieve collection from InMemoryDatabase class?
}
```

which could be called as follows:

```
HashSet<Bike> = GetCollection<Bike>();
```

**Update**

Note that the implementation of GetCollection method should have no prior knowledge of what types of collections are in the InMemoryDatabase class as it gets called from a base class. The solution should be generic. I guess using reflection could be one possible approach?

Comment: could you explain why you need this? there might be a better way.

Comment: `HashSet<Bike> = instanceOfInMemoryDatabase.Bike` ?

Comment: I would agree with Ian, if you already know the type you want then why not just directly access the property that you want? Unless you have a common ancestor or interface otherwise it doesn't make much sense to return a specific hashset type

Comment: var trucks = yourCollection.OfType<Truck>()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want one HashSet per type:

```
  public class InMemoryDatabase
  {
      private Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable> _hashSets = new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable>();

      // Returns or creates a new HashSet for this type.
      public HashSet<T> GetCollection<T>()
      {
          Type t = typeof(T);

          if (!_hashSets.ContainsKey(t))
          {
              _hashSets[t] = new HashSet<T>();
          }

          return (_hashSets[t] as HashSet<T>);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's multiple ways to do it. One way is to simply test the type and return the appropriate field:

```
public HashSet<TEntity> GetCollection<TEntity>() 
{
    var type = typeof(TEntity);

    if(type == typeof(Bike))
       return (HashSet<TEntity>)(object)Bikes;
    if(type == typeof(Car))
       return (HashSet<TEntity>)(object)Cars;
    if(type == typeof(Truck))
       return (HashSet<TEntity>)(object)Trucks;

    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}
```

The intermediary cast to `object` is needed because the compiler doesn't know that `TEntity` is actually one of those types in that case, so we use type erasure to make sure the cast works. It should be optimized out during the JIT step since the method is built for that particular type.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond with your proposed solution

Answer (score 1):

The best approach I see is to reflect the class once and build a "collection selector map" to be used by the generic function like this

```
public class InMemoryDatabase
{
    static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<InMemoryDatabase, object>> collectionMap;
    static InMemoryDatabase()
    {
        collectionMap =
            (from p in typeof(InMemoryDatabase).GetProperties()
             where p.CanRead &&
                p.PropertyType.IsGenericType && 
                p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(HashSet<>)
             select new
             {
                 Type = p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0],
                 Selector = (Func<InMemoryDatabase, object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
                     typeof(Func<InMemoryDatabase, object>), p.GetMethod)
             }).ToDictionary(e => e.Type, e => e.Selector);
    }
    public HashSet<TEntity> GetCollection<TEntity>()
    {
        return (HashSet<TEntity>)collectionMap[typeof(TEntity)](this);
    }
    // Collections
    public HashSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Truck> Trucks { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Bike> Bikes { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond with your proposed solution. I decided to accept buffjape's answer as it avoids the need for reflection.

Comment: @aw1975 That's fine. I was thinking you need both typed and generic accessors (similar to EF custom DbContexts)

Answer (score 1):

This may seem a little crude, but it works even if you don't provide a valid type for TEntity...

```
public class InMemoryDatabase
{
    public HashSet<TEntity> GetCollection<TEntity>()
    {
        var a = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        HashSet<TEntity> retVal = null;
        foreach (var name in a.Select(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name))
        {
            retVal = this.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(this, null) as HashSet<TEntity>;
            if (retVal != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
    public HashSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Truck> Trucks { get; set; }
    public HashSet<Bike> Bikes { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond with your proposed solution. I decided to accept buffjape's answer as it avoids the need for reflection.